# Javascript setting image link and date as object

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, object

I am working on building a website and I need help for the section where I will be listing some of the items that I am presenting in my website. I am using javascript object to store all the info of each individual items and I have a problem storing images and dates in the object.

Since I don't know how to store image inside an object or if that's even possible, I have used the online weblink of the images, and I want to know how to load the image inside the HTML section. The next problem I have is storing date inside a javascript object. I want the dates inside the object to be calculating, and by that I mean to be able to subtract the dates to get the range between the dates or apply arithmetic to it.

I'm not sure if this matters or not, but I am using jQuery for all my js codes.

This is the code for image inside object for now, but I'm not sure how to use this inside HTML.

```
   var object = {
     image : "image link"

    }
```

Comment: Please shared your code

Comment: Mate, there is nothing to share. I am asking if there's a way. I don't know anything

Comment: you can store image links inside the store and append them inside DOM when you need it. I know two ways to do it, first is to create new image by js and append it to dom, second is to keep img tags inside html with empty src and put in the img an src when it needed. To handle dates use moment.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you should create an html element .
In your javascript file, you should use reference to the DOM element and put there a localization of image from your object.

Example

```
var object = { image : "image_link", date: new Date()} // you can operate with Date

$("#my_image").attr("src", object.image);
```

The same is with the Date.

```
<span id="example_span></span>

$('#example_span').text(object.date);
```

Is it you were looking for ?

Comment: Thank you for your time, but what if I want to directly link the picture from the web not locally. Also, how am I supposed to store data in an object? Like a specific syntax.

Comment: you can store your weblinks as a string in your object, and use the reference to them.
var object = {image: "url_of_image"}. 
You should looking at your object as your database. Images are genereted with src links. Just store your weblink in the object, and create an array of objects. The src is only a reference to the image it does not metter, where it is hold on (locally or from the server).

Comment: So how would I write for html and js DOM?

Comment: Look at example.
https://jsfiddle.net/p6f0x2tL/2/
Here i am replacing empty src to the weblink with a button.

Comment: Remember that You can load your data after rendering your DOM. Good luck :)